# Simulink: Bit extraction from 1-Byte Hex

Tags: matlab, simulink

I'm relatively new to Simulink and I am looking for a possibility to extract 1-3 specific bits from one byte.
As far as I know the input format (bin, dec, hex) of the constant is irrelevant for the following!? But how can I say that the constant "1234" is hex and not dec?

In my model I use the "Constant Block" as my source (will be parametrised by a MATLAB variable which comes from a m-file).
A further processing with the "Extract Bits Block" causes an error on incompatible data types.

Can someone help me to deal with this issue?

Greets, poeschlorn

Comment: In Matlab, bin and hex numbers are string that you can convert to decimal using bin2dec, hex2dec. You can't use them in a "constant block". Do this block simply going to a "display"works ? Note that you can configure "display" to give non-decimal value.

Comment: do I understand your point right that I should work with the decimal representation of my hex/bin values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is not the most elegant solution, but I converted my input to decimal and then created a BCD representation of it via OR and AND logic blocks for further use.

Answer (score 2):

You should probably do the conversion hex->dec in your .m initialization file and use this value in Simulink.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the Communications Toolbox/Blockset then you can use the [Integer to Bit Converter](http://www.mathworks.com/help/comm/ref/integertobitconverter.html) block to do a conversion to a vector of binary digits then just extract the "bits" that you want.  The [Bit to Integer Converter](http://www.mathworks.com/help/comm/ref/bittointegerconverter.html) block will do the reverse transformation.

If you don't have the Communicatins Blockset then it wouldn't be hard to do a similar thing to this using a plain MATLAB Function block.

[image]